# What do we gain from chanting the names of Lord Shiva?

Tags: shiva, practice, worship

There are various scriptures enumerate the results one can obtain by chanting the name of Lord Shiva and it is believed that Lord Shiva is pleased very easily as compared to Lord Vishnu and Lord Brahma, if remembered by heart. Apart from a summary of the benefits we can gain from chanting the name of Shiva,I want to know if there is any specific gain associated with the chanting which is not available with other forms of worshiping Lord Shiva such as offering water and flowers on Lingam.

Om namo Shivaya- is the most popular way to chant the name of Lord Shiva. Is there any other such effective way to chant the name of Lord Shiva?

Answer (score 9):

Though, there are numerous scriptures have glorified the name of Lord Shiva in detail but since you are asking for specific gain of chanting his name, so I am answering only that. By chanting the five-syllabled (Namah Shivaya) mantra, even the fallen people (those who do not deserve holy rites) can be liberated. It has been said by Lord Shiva himself in [Shiva Mahapurana, Section 7.2, Vayaviya Samhita, Chapter 13, Translated by J. L. Shastri](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226685.html).

> 10. Yes, surely, if the fallen man, under delusion, were to worship me with other mantras, excluding the five-syllabled one, he is sure to fall into hell.
> 11. Persons who live on water or air and those whose bodies are emaciated due to holy rites do not attain my region through those holy rites.
> 12. **But he who worships me even once with devotion repeating the five-syllabled mantra, attains my region through the weightiness of this Mantra alone**.
> 13. Hence, penances, sacrifices, observances and holy rites are not equal to even a croreth part of the worship with the five-syllabled mantra.
> 14. Indeed he who worships me with the five-syllabled mantra becomes liberated if he is in bondage.
> 15. He who worships me even once with the five-syllabled mantra with or without the Rudra mantra is liberated even if he is a fallen or a foolish man.
> 16. O goddess, he who worships me with the six-syllabled or with the five-syllabled mantra, with the Vedic mantra as its ancillary, with devotion to me, is liberated.

Some other glorification of five-syllabled mantra is present in [Shiva Mahapurana, Section 1, Vidyeshvara Samhita, Chapter 17](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc225562.html). In this chapter it is mentioned that by chanting this mantra one can be freed from indebtedness.

> 36-37. The months of Māgha and Bhādrapada are the most auspicious of all occasions. During the days of Japa be shall take only a single meal during the day in limited quantities. He shall abstain from useless talk and curb all his sense organs. He shall uninterruptedly render service to his parents and the king, or any master whom he serves. **By performing the Japa a thousand times, he shall be free from indebtedness**, otherwise not.

According to [Shiva Mahapurana, Section 7.2, Vayaviya Samhita, Chapter 12](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226684.html), all sins will be wiped off by chanting five-syllabled (Namah Shivaya) or six-syllabled (Om Namah Shivaya) mantra.

> 37. A person steady in the Japa of the five-syllabled mantra is released from the cage of sins whether he be a Śūdra, base-born, fool or a learned man.

Also, it is said by Lord Krishna in [Mahabharata, Book 13: Anushasana Parva, SECTION XVII](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a017.htm) at the end of thousand names of Lord Shiva that:

> "Krishna continued, 'That person, O Partha, who recites this hymn with a pure heart observing the vow of Brahmacharyya, and with his senses under control, regularly for one whole year, succeeds in obtaining the fruits of a horse-sacrifice. Danavas and Yakshas and Rakshasas and Pisachas and Yatudhanas and Guhyakas and snakes can do no injury to him.'"

Comment: You can also add what the Phalasruti of any Shiva Sahasranam says. In that way ur answer will be more complete.

Comment: @Rickross I think you can help me here :)

Comment: You can use [this](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/articles/CHATURVIDHA%20SHIVA%20SAHASRANAMA.html) link if u want. It has 4 Shiva Sahsranamas. Since OP is asking what is the benefit of chanting Shiva's names then the Phalasrutis of the stotras will be useful.

Comment: @Rickross Added Mahabharata version.

Answer (score 1):

We obtain the fruition of our wishes and example is how Vyasa obtained his wishes.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm

> Vaisampayana said, 'After Vasudeva had ceased to speak, the great Yogin, viz. the Island-born Krishna, addressed Yudhisthira, saying,--O son, do thou recite this hymn consisting of the thousand and eight names of Mahadeva, and let Maheswara be gratified with thee. In former days, O son, I was engaged in the practice of severe austerities on the breast of the mountains of Meru from desire of obtaining a son. **It is this very hymn that was recited by me. As the reward of this, I obtained the fruition of all my wishes, O son of Pandu. Thou wilt also, by reciting this same hymn, obtain from Sarva the fruition of all thy wishes.**

---

This hymn leads to heaven. It dispels disease and bestows long life.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a017.htm

> From Markandeya, O Janarddana, I obtained it as the reward of my vows and fasts. To thee, O slayer of foes, I communicate that hymn unheard by others. **This hymn leads to heaven. It dispels disease and bestows long life.** This is worthy of the highest praise, and is consistent with the Vedas.'

Parashurama recited the hymn and got the wishes he wanted.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm

> Then Jamadagni's son, that foremost of all righteous persons, shining like the Sun with blazing splendour in the midst of that conclave of Rishis, said unto the son of Kunti these words;--**I was afflicted with the sin, O eldest son of Pandu, of Brahmanicide for having slain my brothers who were all learned Brahmanas.** For purifying myself, I sought the protection, O king, of Mahadeva. **I hymned the praises of the great Deity by reciting his names**. At this, **Bhava became gratified with me and gave me a battle-axe and many other celestial weapons.** And he said unto me,--**Thou shalt be freed from sin and thou shalt be invincible in battle; Death himself shall not succeed in overcoming thee for thou shalt be freed from disease.**--Even thus did the illustrious and crested Deity of auspicious form said unto me. **Through the grace of that Deity of supreme intelligence I obtained all that He had said.**

---

A person who recites this hymn by subjugating their senses obtains the merit of horse- sacrifice.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a018.htm

> That person who, subjugating his senses and purifying himself, recites this hymn, without interruption in respect of his vow, for one month, succeeds in obtaining the merit that is attached to a Horse-sacrifice.

Brahma who recites this succeeds in acquiring all vedas, Kshatriya is crowned with victory, vaisya obtains wealth and cleverness, and sudra, happiness and good end.

> That person who, subjugating his senses and purifying himself, recites this hymn, without interruption in respect of his vow, for one month, succeeds in obtaining the merit that is attached to a Horse-sacrifice. By reciting this hymn the Brahmana succeeds in acquiring all the Vedas; the Kshatriya becomes crowned with victory, O son of Pritha; the Vaisya becomes successful in obtaining wealth and cleverness; and the Sudra, in winning happiness here and a good end hereafter.

People of great fame who recite this hymn set their heart on Rudra.

> Persons of great fame, by reciting this prince of hymns that is competent to cleanse every sin and that is highly sacred and purifying, set their hearts on Rudra.

A man lives in heaven for as many pores are there in his body.

> A man by reciting this prince of hymns succeeds in living in heaven for as many years as there are pores in his body.'"

If a person even devastates the entire universe, he is not stained of sin if he worships Shiva.

> A person who raises houses to the ground and destroys tanks and lakes indeed, who devastates the whole universe, does not become stained with sin, if he adores and worships the illustrious Deity of three eyes.

A person stained of all types of sins is freed from it by meditating upon Mahadeva.

> A person who raises houses to the ground and destroys tanks and lakes indeed, who devastates the whole universe, does not become stained with sin, if he adores and worships the illustrious Deity of three eyes.

If Rudra be gratified, he can bestow high boons.

> If Rudra be gratified with a person, he can confer upon him the states of ether Brahma or of Kesava or of Sakra with all the deities under him, or the sovereignty of the three worlds. Those men, O sire, who worship Bhava even mentally, succeed in freeing themselves from all sins and attain to a residence in heaven with all the gods.